# How to solve "error executing aggreation pipeline: variable 'XYZ' not bound" in MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework, restheart

I am using [Restheart](http://restheart.org/) and MongoDB and also new in these, I have to write aggregation in MongoDb. I written aggregation in mongoDb with $match.

**Here Sample Code:**

```
  {
    "aggrs": [{
            "type": "pipeline",
            "uri": "aggregation_by_time",
            "stages": [{
                    "_$match": {
                        "bus::destination": {
                            "_$in": {
                                "_$var": "stand"
                            }
                        },
                        "bus::eta": {
                            "_$gte": {
                                "_$var": "fromDate"
                            },
                            "_$lte": {
                                "_$var": "toDate"
                            }
                        },
                        "tickets": {
                            "_$eq": {
                                "_$var": "isConfirmedTravel"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }]
          }
```

**Here Sample Access Url:**

```
http://..xyz../_aggrs/aggregation_by_time?avars={"stand":["A","B","C","D","E","F"]}
```

When I access this url then it is not working, displaying some error.

**Error:**

> {"http status code":400,"http status description":"Bad
>   Request","message":"error executing aggreation pipeline: variable
>   isConfirmedTravel not bound"}

**When I access below url Then it will work.**

```
http://..xyz../_aggrs/aggregation_by_time?avars={"stand":["A","B","C","D","E","F"],"isConfirmedTravel":"true"}
```

So I want to make optional $match, Like if I don't mention as a parmater "isConfirmedTravel" in url, then it should work. And If I want to send as parameter "isConfirmedTravel" in url then It should also work. But In my case If put field in $match then you should have to mention in url. Thats why I want to set optional  "isConfirmedTravel":"true" field. If I call then it should work and if I will not call then url should be work.

Comment: You probably want to mention what http wrapper you are using. Mongo itself does not have an http interface.

Comment: I am Using restheart

Comment: [docs](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/display/RH02X/Aggregation#Aggregation-Passingvariablestoaggregationoperations) say nothing about optional variables, so I reckon you need to register 2 separate aggregations with and w/o isConfirmedTravel.

Comment: @Alex Blex I have seen on url https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2013/06/21/aggregation-in-mongodb/ for the some 'or' and 'and condition'. But I am not able to understood.

Comment: The link is for native aggregation. The error you have comes from Restheart.

Comment: @AlexBlex SO I have to write two aggregation ?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding of the issue. If you have luxury of time, you can wait a bit longer if anybody posts a better approach.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks a lots for giving me your time.

Comment: I do not know if your problem is solved but if it is not the case the solution is that in fact in the url it is necessary to declare all your vars here it thus misses the declaration of fromDate and toDate